# How is the Ubuntu root CA store created?

Tags: openssl, https, certificates, tls

I know that the root store is located at `/etc/ssl/certs` and can be updated with `update-ca-certificates`. But where does it get it's certificates from? And how do browsers interact with it which have their own root store. What's the priority ranking herer?

Comment: See for instance: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

Comment: I've seen this documents, but it does now answer my questions. Have you read both, the document and my question?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the certificates to the folder `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and make sure they end with the extension `.crt`. When you run `update-ca-certificates` it will do more than just update to `/etc/ssl/certs`, it will also create the java `cacerts` file (tested with openjdk 8).